# Splitting items in a Listbox into parallel lists

Tags: vb.net

For each line in the display listbox I need to break the line into substrings: year and temperature, convert them and insert their values into the parallel lists. I am very frustrated because I am sure it is simple but I have been up all night working on this project.

The listbox data I am working with is from a csv file I imported and contains data that looks like this

1999, 6.654616
2000, 8.616851
2001, 6.61681

Here is my current code.

```
'Open File Dialog
        Dim dlg As New OpenFileDialog With {
            .Filter = "CSV Files|*.csv|Text Files|*.txt|All Files|*.*",
            .Title = "Please select CSV Data",
            .InitialDirectory = "C:\"
        }
        dlg.ShowDialog()

        'Declaring streamreader object

        R = New IO.StreamReader(dlg.FileName)
        While (R.Peek() > -1)
            ListBoxDisplay.Items.Add(R.ReadLine)
        End While
        R.Close()
        'Testing
        'List
        Dim year As New List(Of Integer)
        Dim avgtemp As New List(Of Double)
```

Comment: I don't see any splitting going on there.

Answer (score 0):

String.Split should work for you.

```
Private Sub GetLists()
        Dim year As New List(Of Integer)
        Dim avgtemp As New List(Of Double)
        While (R.Peek() > -1))
            Dim line As String = R.ReadLine
            ListBoxDisplay.Items.Add(line)
            Dim strArray() As String = line.Split(","c)
            year.Add(CInt(strArray(0)))
            avgtemp.Add(CDbl(strArray(1).Trim))
        End While
        R.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, as you can tell I am very new to vb.net. The only problem is the professor wants us to use parallel lists instead of an Array. These lists of numbers will then be passed to a function.

Comment: I believe the year list and the avgtemp list are parallel lists. I have not heard that term before; parallel arrays yes, but not parallel lists. I assume the concept is the same.